# How does a Hub work when sending broadcast packages?

Tags: ethernet

I know that hubs send broadcast packets, so every packets is received by each node in the broadcast domain. I read that frames that are received but that aren't addressed to a NIC'S MAC address are dropped. But I mean if it is a broadcast packet, it shouldn't be accepted by each node?

Comment: Hubs are obsolete since way back. Do you perhaps mean switch?

Comment: Nono, I mean hubs and I refer to this [post](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59040/why-can-a-packet-sniffer-in-an-ethernet-lan-obtain-all-packets-sent-over-the-lan)

Comment: "I know that hubs send broadcast packets, so every packets is received by each node in the broadcast domain. I read that frames that are received but that aren't addressed to a NIC'S MAC address are dropped. " -- true for hubs. Broadcast packets don't really make sense with repeaters (hubs), only for switches.

Comment: But the hub broadcasts packets to all his ports

Comment: There is a difference between "mindless" repeating (what a hub does) and broadcasting (what a switch does) . To be precise, broadcasting is something that a switch "chooses" to do, while a hub will repeat what it "hears" "mindlessly".

Comment: So the hub repeats packets to all his ports, but a packet coming out from a hub doesn't have a  FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF mac address so?

Comment: Hubs have no idea what they are sending. Hubs merely amplify and repeat the signals received to all other hub interfaces.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hubs are layer 1 devices. As they receive electrical impulses constituting a frame, they forward them out all ports other than the receiving port.

This is regardless of whether the l2 destination is unicast, multicast, or broadcast (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff).

This may result in an Ethernet collision if multiple hosts transmit traffic to the hub simultaneously.

A host’s Ethernet adapter will pass certain received frames up the protocol stack for further processing ( generating a cpu interrupt)

1. Unicast frames which match its Ethernet unicast address
2. Multicast frames destined to any l2 multicast address which the host is “listening” to
3. All broadcast l2 frames

If the l2 frame includes a l3 packet, the host cpu will de-encapsulate and process it.

If the interface is placed in “promiscuous mode” ( by tcpdump for example) it is possible for all received Ethernet frames to be sent up the protocol stack and generate interrupts.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that hubs send broadcast packets

Hubs don't send anything (by themselves). They *forward* bits (or symbols) on the wire, regardless of framing and addressing.

> so every packets is received by each node in the broadcast domain.

Every frame is forwarded to each hub port and ending up on each node in the broadcast domain, yes. With a repeater hub, the broadcast domain is identical to the collision domain.

> I read that frames that are received but that aren't addressed to a NIC'S MAC address are dropped.

By the NIC, yes.

> But I mean if it is a broadcast packet, it shouldn't be accepted by each node?

A NIC (not in promiscuous mode) processes frames addressed to its MAC or the broadcast address or a multicast address that it was configured for. All other frames are dropped/ignored.

Early Ethernet relied on the NICs sorting out unwanted frames as the shared wire transmitted each frame to all the nodes on the wire. A repeater hub replicates that behavior in that it copies each bit from the receiving port to all other ports. Only one port can be receiving at any time, anything else received causes a collision. It doesn't make any difference to where that bit's frame is addressed to as a repeater (hub) has no concept of frames and addressing.

Addressing does make a difference with switches that selectively forward unicasts by MAC address. They handle broadcasts similar to how a repeater handles everything: the broadcast is "flooded" out of all ports but the one it was received on.

Comment: Thanks, but for example in a network with 3 computer A,B,C (no-one in promiscuous mode). Supposing arp cache are empty, A pings B, why a sniffer in C can see arp request/reply and ICMP request/reply?

Comment: @Fab996 I assume you're referring to a repeated, single collision domain network? All traffic between A and B is also physically seen by C's NIC - but unless it's broadcast (ARP request) it's dropped there (unicast ARP reply). A sniffer usually activates promiscuous mode, so it's able to capture the unicast traffic as well.

Comment: So a sniffer not in promiscuous mode shouldn't see ARP reply and ICMP request/reply because they are unicast? How can i check with tcpdump, I used this command tcpdump -p -enni <interface>, is it right?

Comment: A sniffer not using promiscuous mode won't see alien unicast, e.g. ARP replies from B sent as unicast to A. The `-p` should stop `tcpdump` from using promiscuous mode.

Comment: Ah okay because in the comment above you said "is also physically seen by C's NIC", so I thought that the sniffer sees unicast packets but then they are dropped, but maybe I understood wrong. So unicast traffic is not seen by a sniffer working in a no promiscuous mode?

Comment: When the NIC drops a frame it is physically received but not passed to the driver/OS. As stated before, the NIC drops all frames that carry none of the addresses it is configured with (hardware MAC, broadcast, other MACs, multicast), so C's NIC drops frames sent to B's NIC.

Comment: Thanks, so for example during a MAC flooding the attacker's NIC should be in promiscuous mode in order to sniff packets?

Comment: Generally, yes, MAC flooding attack or not. A sniffer only works for local traffic unless the NIC is in promiscuous mode.